# drawImage doesn't work when I refer to an image in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

(I'll show the pure javascript below) I've got these two lines of code that are, in my mind, doing the exact same thing but one of them reports an error.  This appears in a file named "Rendering.coffee". Here are the two lines (in coffeescript):

```
...
ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("bg"), 0, 0)  #this works
ctx.drawImage(root.resources.bg, 0, 0)  #TypeError: Value could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.
...
```

I assign `root.resources.bg` in another file named "Resources.coffee" like this:

```
root = exports ? this
root.resources = {}

root.resources.bg = document.getElementById("bg")
```

Here's the html that loads all the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Canvas tutorial</title>

    <script src="Resources.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Rendering.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <style>
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body onload="window['core'].startGame();">
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<img id="bg" src="bg.png" style="display: none">

</body>
</html>
```

When I change the rendering code to this, I get no error:

```
root.resources.bg = document.getElementById("bg")
ctx.drawImage(root.resources.bg, 0, 0)
```

or

```
bg = document.getElementById("bg")
ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0)
```

That makes me think there's something more fundamentally wrong here.  Can I only use `img` tags after I've already created the canvas context?  If I change my "Resources.js" to print out the value of the `bg` variable it prints "null", but if I print it in the "Rendering.js" it prints `[object HTMLImageElement]`  Why is it null in the "Resources.js"?

This is firefox, by the way.

---

## Javascript

Rendering.js:

```
...
ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("bg"), 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(root.resources.bg, 0, 0);
...
```

Resources.js:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.2
(function() {
  var root;

  root = typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null ? exports : this;

  root.resources = {};

  root.resources.bg = document.getElementById("bg");

}).call(this);
```

---

**TL;DR:** Why am I getting this error when I assign my image outside of my rendering function?  `#TypeError: Value could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.`

---

## My First Attempt at a Solution

This worked for me, but I'm not sure if it's a good solution:

```
root = exports ? this
root.resources = {}

bgResource = undefined

root.resources.bg = ->
  if not bgResource
    bgResource = document.getElementById("bg")
  return bgResource
```

Then I call this as `root.resources.bg()`

Comment: Normally, drawImage works fine with a saved reference to an img element, so something is wrong.  What does Firebug say about the value of root.resources.bg if you put a breakpoint just before the drawImage?

Comment: And if you put the two scripts to the bottom of your html file, before </body>?  (could be that the DOM is not ready at the time you initialize the resource). Could you also do a `console.log(root.resources.bg)` and see what console says it contains.

Comment: +1 for Ken : the DOM will not be ready when document.getElementById gets called.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to solve this two ways -

### Method 1

Move the scripts to the bottom of the file before the closing tag `</body>`. This way all DOM elements are loaded before any JavaScript is executed.

### Method 2

Try to wrap all inits that are dependent on DOM elements in the `window`'s `load` event inside the script files themselves in case you cannot or don't want to move them to the bottom:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    /// init the resource here...

}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I solved this in a different way (see my edit at the bottom of my question).  Does this seem like a decent "Method 3" or is it a bad idea?

Comment: @tieTYT perhaps a bit hack-ish IMO. There is still the risk of the DOM not being properly loaded at the second attempt. The most secure way of knowing is to use the load event (there is also a `ready` event). This event is explicitly called for this purpose so why not use it? :)